# Integer Overflow project euler 8 - C

Tags: c, codeblocks

I read previous posts on this project euler problem but I still cant figure it out. I tried to use the initial condition (the 4 adjacent digit products) and it works for that. Upon trying to find the product of 13 digits, it gives me the following

`2091059712` when using `long`, `int`, and `long long` casting
   `3780710640` when using `unsigned long`

When I try to find the greatest product of 4 adjacent digits, I get the correct answer of `5832`. I am using a 64 bit system on Windows 10, C programming and not C++.

Edited: Switched to Long long for num and larg, and used %I64d instead of %u and should work!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int char2int(const char n) {
    return n - '0';
}

int prob8() {
    char number[] = 
        "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    unsigned long num = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int mark = 0;

    unsigned long larg = 1;

    while (mark != 987) {
        i = mark;
        while (i != (mark + 13)) {
            num *= char2int(number[i]);
            i++;
        }

        if (num > larg) {
            larg = num;
        }

        num = 1;
        mark++;
    }

    printf("%u", larg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyone? I tried taking some other guys code and trying it on my codeblocks. I got the same answers :S

Comment: When you post code, you should add a tag for the language being used. It helps people find the question and it also affects the syntax coloring.

Comment: How many bits does your `unsigned long` have? How many bits do you need? Consider using `int64_t` from `stdint.h` when you really need a 64 bit int. Also, "%u" is not the right format for printing a 64 bit int.

Comment: @crashmstr I did if you would look at the last line of my comments. 
Paul i dont know how to check that out I am still a noob
It is what I googled and saw

Comment: No, you *mention* in the *title* and the *body* that you are using C, but I added the *tag* for C language. Tags are an important part of the question.

Comment: I apologize then :( I only tagged Codeblocks, I 'll will tag C next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9^13` is `0x24F_D302_7FE9` so you'll need an integer type with at least 42 bits, i.e. a 64-bit integer.

In mingw32-gcc 4.9.2, `sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT` results in `32`, so that type won't work.

`sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT` results in `64`, so that will work.

You said that using `long long` didn't work... but it should have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>

int char2int(const char n){
    return n-'0';
}

int prob8(){

    char number[]="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    long long num=1;
    int i=0;
    int mark=0;

    long long larg=1;

    while(mark!=987){
        i=mark;
        while(i!=(mark+13)){
            num*=char2int(number[i]);
            i++;
        }

        if(num>larg){
            larg=num;
        }

        num=1;
        mark++;
    }


    printf("%I64d\n", larg);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT);
    prob8();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
32
64
23514624000
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! It took me ages to do this problem. Thanks so much !

Comment: Yes, how do I do that?

Comment: I tried to click on the up arrow butit said I am not high enough rep